# Multiple initially selected values in a dynamic select list with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Thanks in advance for your help. This list is to update an existing record, so it's populated from a database with `$rs_fullcat` then checked with another recordset `$rs_cat` for the initially selected values. I can only get it to initially select one value, the first one in `$rs_cat`, but I need it to select all of the existing options from the database. I feel like I'm close but I can't find the answer anywhere. Here's the code:

```
<select name="category" multiple="multiple" id="category">
<?php
do {  
?>
<option value="<?php echo $row_rs_fullcat['categoryID']?>"<?php if (!(strcmp($row_rs_fullcat['categoryID'], $row_rs_cat['categoryID']))) {echo "selected=\"selected\"";} ?>><?php echo $row_rs_fullcat['category_name']?></option>
<?php
} while ($row_rs_fullcat = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_fullcat));
$rows = mysql_num_rows($rs_fullcat);
if($rows > 0) {
  mysql_data_seek($rs_fullcat, 0);
  $row_rs_fullcat = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_fullcat);
}
?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do, is first select (and fetch) all the selected ones from the database, and put them in a variable (`$rs_cat` in your case). Then, in your `while` loop it's a simple matter of doing an `in_array()` check to see if the value is selected.

Comment: That makes sense but I can't seem get it to work. Could you please give me an example of doing the `in_array()` in my `while` loop?